# Progressbar each jquery ui optimized

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, each

How could I optimize the following jquery script to make it work for different classes:

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rvalverde/DaF5H/

jQuery UI:

```
    var $pG300 = $('#telefono-80').progressbar();
    var pGress300 = setInterval(function() {
            var pVal300 = $pG300.progressbar('option', 'value');
            var pCnt30 = !isNaN(pVal300) ? (pVal300 + 1) : 1;
            if (pCnt30 > 40) {
                    clearInterval(pGress3);
            } else {
                    $pG300.progressbar({
                            value : pCnt30
                    });
            }
    }, 10);


    var $pG3000 = $('#telefono-140').progressbar();
    var pGress300 = setInterval(function() {
            var pVal3000 = $pG3000.progressbar('option', 'value');
            var pCnt30 = !isNaN(pVal3000) ? (pVal3000 + 1) : 1;
            if (pCnt30 > 70) {
                    clearInterval(pGress3);
            } else {
                    $pG3000.progressbar({
                            value : pCnt30
                    });
            }
    }, 10);


    var $pG30000 = $('#telefono-200').progressbar();
    var pGress3000 = setInterval(function() {
            var pVal30000 = $pG30000.progressbar('option', 'value');
            var pCnt30 = !isNaN(pVal30000) ? (pVal30000 + 1) : 1;
            if (pCnt30 > 100) {
                    clearInterval(pGress3);
            } else {
                    $pG30000.progressbar({
                            value : pCnt30
                    });
            }
    }, 10);
```

Example HTML:

```
<div id="telefono-80" class="progressbar"></div>
<div id="telefono-140" class="progressbar"></div>
<div id="telefono-200" class="progressbar"></div>
```

Example Optimized:

```
<div value="80" class="progressbar"></div>
<div value="140" class="progressbar"></div>
<div value="200" class="progressbar"></div>
```

What would be the best way to optimize the js code?

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rvalverde/DaF5H/

Comment: What are you trying to optimize? Reduce the lines of code or the execution time when you have hundreds of those on the same page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do it like this, without the ugly intervals :)

HTML

```
<div class="progressbar" data-value="80"></div>
<div class="progressbar" data-value="140"></div>
<div class="progressbar" data-value="200"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.ui-progressbar-value {
  transition: width 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.5s;
}
```

JS

```
$('.progressbar').progressbar();
$('.progressbar').each(function () {
  var val = parseInt($(this).data('value'));
  var percent = val * (100 / 200);
  $(this).progressbar('option', 'value', percent);
})
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DaF5H/2/)

**Update**

Even better, you can avoid the extra iteration using the [create](http://api.jqueryui.com/1.8/progressbar/#event-create) callback as follows:

```
$('.progressbar').progressbar({
  create: function () {
    var val = parseInt($(this).data('value'));
    var percent = val * (100 / 200);
    $(this).progressbar('option', 'value', percent);
  }
});
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DaF5H/4/)

Answer (score 0):

I've refactorized your code.
This way you encapsulate the logic in one function:

```
function createProgressBar(DOMbar, value){
    var pGress3000 = setInterval(function() {
        var $pG30000 = DOMbar.progressbar();
        var pVal300 = $pG30000.progressbar('option', 'value');
        var pCnt30 = !isNaN(pVal300) ? (pVal300 + 1) : 1;
        if (pCnt30 > value) {
            clearInterval(pGress3);
        } else {
            DOMbar.progressbar({
                value : pCnt30
            });
        }     
    }, 10); 
}

createProgressBar($('#telefono-80'), 40);
createProgressBar($('#telefono-140'), 70);
createProgressBar($('#telefono-200'), 100);
```

And this is the new [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DaF5H/1/)

Of course, it would be better to rename the variables to make them more descriptive.

Answer (score 0):

I've optimized your code to the best possible.
Basically I iterated the code and used **"rel"** tag

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DaF5H/3/)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="parent">
    <div rel="80" class="progressbar"></div>
    <div rel="35" class="progressbar"></div>
    <div rel="50" class="progressbar"></div>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('.parent').find('.progressbar').each(function(){
    var a = parseInt($(this).attr('rel'));
    $(this).progressbar({
        value : a
    });
});
```